# How to add gap between two bars (same stackId) in bar graph in recharts

Tags: recharts

I don't understand how to add a gap between two stackId's. I have tried to add an extra bar and I am giving the color white which is working fine for small values. Is there any another way to find the gap between two stackId.

Code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import BarChart from '@bit/recharts.recharts.bar-chart';
import Bar from '@bit/recharts.recharts.bar';
import XAxis from '@bit/recharts.recharts.x-axis';
import YAxis from '@bit/recharts.recharts.y-axis';
import CartesianGrid from '@bit/recharts.recharts.cartesian-grid';
import Tooltip from '@bit/recharts.recharts.tooltip';
import Legend from '@bit/recharts.recharts.legend';

const data = [
{
    name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400,
},
{
    name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210,
},
{
    name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290,
},
{
    name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000,
},
{
    name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181,
},
{
    name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500,
},
{
    name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100,
},
];

export default class Example extends PureComponent {
render() {
    return (
        <BarChart
            width={500}
            height={300}
            data={data}
            margin={{
                top: 20, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
            }}
        >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="name" />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend />
            <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" />
            <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" fill="#82ca9d" />
        </BarChart>
    );
    }
    }
```

Screenshot:

[screenshot for bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz7ce.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a bigger gap between to Bars, you can use the `barCategoryGap`, in which you specify how much gap you need between two Bars in px. However, using this property will also make your bars thiner. To have your Bars look wider, you'll simply need to change the `width` of the `BarChart` to a bigger value.

In the end, you could have something of the like:

```
<BarChart
  width={600}
  barCategoryGap={15}
  height={300}
[...]
```

With the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying me @PeterSmith . But I not asking gab between two bars , I am asking vertical separate gap between two color (ex: green one and purple one ) above mentioned your image.

Comment: Oh ok, that was not clear in your question, sorry for my misunderstanding. (And who's PeterSmith? ;))

Comment: sorry by mistake that name was tagged in comment.

Comment: I hope u can help on my above question. gap b/w two colors.

Comment: The solution you thought of (with an addition stack between the two others) is pretty good and should work, were you able to do it? If not I could provide you with an example.

Comment: sorry for the late reply could you please provide me the solution for a separator b/w the two stacks.